# Open ball is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I denote with $B(x_0;\rho)$ the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \text{s.t.} \ \|x-x_0|<\rho\}$.

My textbook proves this lemma: "The $B(a;\delta)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for every $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\delta \ge 0$." in the following way: "Proof. For arbitrary $b \in B(a;\delta)$ set $\beta=\| b-a \|$, then $\delta-\beta>0$. Hence $B(b,\delta-\beta) \subset B(a;\delta)$, because for every $x \in B(b,\delta-\beta)$ it is $\|x-a\| \le \|x-b\| +\|b-a\|<\delta-\beta+\beta=\delta$."

I can't build the intuition behind this.

Before this lemma, my textbook says that a set $X$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $X=\text{int}(X)$. So, if I'm not wrong, the lemma is equivalent to show that $B(a;\delta)=\text{int} \left(B(a;\delta)\right)$ and since two sets are equal if one contains the other and is contained in the other, knowing that it is always true that the interior of a set is contained in the set itself, it remains to show that $B(a;\delta) \subset \text{int}\left(B(a;\delta)\right)$.

But an interior point of a set is a point such that there exists a ball centered in that point contained in the set, and since the interior of a set is the set of all the interior points, if I'm not wrong it should be $\text{int}\left(B(a;\delta)\right)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \text{s.t.} \ \exists r>0 \ B(x;r) \subset B(a;\delta) \}$; from this, I tried to build intuition and thought that the worst case scenario is when the boundary of the internal balls $B(x;r)$ touch the boundary of the external ball $B(a;\delta)$, and this surely doesn't happen if the distance between the center $c_1$ of any internal ball $B(c_1;R_1)$ and the center $a$ of the external ball $B(a;\delta)$ is less than $\delta-R_1$. This distance seems to be the $\beta$ that the textbook defines, but I am not sure if this is the reasoning that the author uses to be sure that every $x \in B(b;\delta-\beta)$ belongs to $B(a;\delta)$ as well and he is tacitly trying to prove that the ball is contained in its interior (because, as you can read, nothing is mentioned about that) or he is using another reasoning which is more intuitive and geometrical and I am overthinking this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think drawing a little picture would help immensely with intuition.

Comment: Given a point $b \in B(\alpha; \delta)$, maybe you can build intuition for why the distance between $b$ and the closest point on the boundary $\partial B(\alpha; \delta)$ is $\beta$?